# What is the maximum number of external IP for one Google Cloud Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to use Google Cloud instance as the VPN server with multiple external IP addresses.

What is the maximum number of external IPs I can use for one Google Cloud instance? (In documentation it is mentioned that "The maximum number of network interfaces per instance is 8" but I'm not sure is it mean I have a limit of 8 IP per instance or 8 subnets with lot of IPs )

Also, this is probably the dumbest question (I'm totally new to cloud computing area) but if for example, one external IP of the instance is 1.1.1.1 Does it mean I can connect to instance from internet by this IP as well as if some software run on the instance and connect another server it will show in log that connection was from 1.1.1.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compute engine can have multiple network interfaces.  Each network interface can have BOTH an internal and external IP address.  This means that if there is limit of 8 network interfaces, you can only have 8 external IP addresses.

(Source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)

It is my understanding that if you have an internal IP address associated with a network interface of a Compute Engine (say 1.1.1.1) and then associate that interface with an external IP address then any traffic arriving at the compute engine through the external IP address will appear (to the Compute Engine) will log as though it had been sent to the internal IP address.

Comment: Hi Kolban, This is not entirely correct. Compute Engine network interfaces are not assigned public IP addresses. Instead, a special type of ONE-TO-ONE NAT is used and the NAT is assigned the public IP address. This is why traffic arrives on the internal IP address.